# MySQL many-to-many SELECT query

Tags: mysql

I have a **Product** table, a **Tags** table and a table that links them together, **ProductTags**.

**Product**

```
ID
```

**ProductTags**

```
ProductID
TagID
```

**Tags**

```
ID
```

I want to query the `ProductTags` table for all `ProductIDs` that have both `TagID` 1 and 2.  How would I do this?

```
SELECT *
From ProductTags
Where TagID = 1
    AND TagID = 2
```

This obviously won't work... can't quite get my head round how to do it!

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: You might increase your chances of getting an answer if you create an [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/). Make it easy for people to answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a "set-within-sets" query and I like to solve these using `group by` and `having`.  Here is one method:

```
SELECT ProductId
FROM ProductTags
WHERE TagID IN (1, 2)
GROUP BY ProductId
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT TagId) = 2;
```

Comment: This worked perfectly.  I wasnt aware of "IN" within WHERE, its great! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to use group by and having for this case

```
select 
p.id
from product p
join producttags pt on pt.ProductID = p.id
join tags t on t.id = pt.tagid
where pt.tagid in (1,2)
group by p.id
having count(*) = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try joining the `ProductTags` table twice.

```
SELECT t3 From ProductTags t1 join  ProductTags t2 on t1.productId=t2.productId join Product t3 Where t1.TagID = 1 AND t2.TagID = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
SELECT * From ProductTags
Where TagID = 1 OR TagID = 2
```